# I do not have lvm_GetSelectionMark in my commctrl.h

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I needed to get the id of the focused item from a listview using a handle:

```
    int selected = (int)SendMessage(hWnd, LVM_GETSELECTIONMARK, 0, 0);
```

However, I get an error that LVM_GETSELECTIONMARK was not declared in this scope? Is there something wrong with my library because the macro ListView_GetSelectionMark(hWnd) does not exist either.

Also, I did include commctrl.h in the header.

Thank you.

Comment: I have found the same issue no message or macro in Commcrtl.h

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your project. For some reason these are missing from the Commcrtl.h included with Codeblocks IDE.

```
#define LVM_GETSELECTIONMARK    (LVM_FIRST+66)
#define ListView_GetSelectionMark(w) (INT)SNDMSG((w),LVM_GETSELECTIONMARK,0,0)
```